# Protractor Test cases execution fails when try to run on Headless Chrome V71

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

I'm using protractor for my e2e tests. 
Recently we updated to Chrome 71 and Webdriver 2.45 and now we constantly
get the error: "chrome not reachable" when running headless.

If we do not run headless our tests pass. Because headless tests are more consistent en faster I still want to use headless mode.

On chrome 70 and webdriver 2.44 we had no problems at all.

```
        args: [
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--disable-impl-side-painting',
            '--disable-gpu-sandbox',
            '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
            '--disable-accelerated-jpeg-decoding',
            '--disable-popup-blocking',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--test-type=ui',
            '--start-maximized',
            '--window-size=1800,1000',
            '--headless'
        ]
```

WebDriverError: chrome not reachable
         (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.80)
         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615355 (d5698f682d8b2742017df6c81e0bd8e6a3063189),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.1 x86_64)

Any thoughts?

Comment: The same thing happened to us on Windows: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

Comment: Hi, did you find a workaround for this problem, by chance?

Answer (score 1):

The cause in our case is most likely to be this bug in either ChromeDriver or Chrome headless:

- [Unable to download a file when using in headless mode (selenium, chromedriver)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=916113)

Some of our tests trigger file downloads, and it appears that ChromeDriver or Chrome headless freezes from that point onward, responding to any further requests with "chrome not reachable".

Comment: Same here all my tests are failed in Chrome71